# How does this code work to compress a file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have read this line of code:

```
compress_size_bzip2=$(bzip2 "$file" ; stat -c %s "$file.bz2")
```

Can anyone help me to understand this command and how I can write this code in other ways?

Comment: This is not a question about Ubuntu. In the future, when asking general questions about Unix and Linux, you should use that stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12):

Let's break this command down.

1. `compress_size_bzip2=anything` sets the value of shell variable called `compress_size_bzip2` (just a name without special meaning) to `anything` that is written on the right hand of `=` sign.
2. That `anything` in our case is `$(command)`. This is a **command substitution**; value of this construct is equal to whatever `command` writes out in the output.
3. The `command` is: `bzip2 "$file" ; stat -c %s "$file.bz2"`, so actually two commands executed one after the other. The first command, `bzip2 "$file"` compresses the file whose name is taken from the shell variable `file`. The quotes are there in case the name contains spaces. Normally this command does not write anything. The second command, `stat -c %s "$file.bz2"`, outputs the size of the file whose name is the value of shell variable `file` plus the extension `.bz2`.

So that size is the output of the whole `command`, and it is assigned to the variable `compress_size_bzip2`.

If you set the variable `file` to the filename you want to compress, for example `file=myfile.txt`, and then run the above line, two things will happen:

1. the file `myfile.txt` will be compressed into `myfile.txt.bz2`
2. the size of the file `myfile.txt.bz2` will be assigned to variable `compress_size_bzip2`. You can display this value with the command `echo $compress_size_bzip2`.

Answer (score 7):

1. ```bsh
   bzip2 "$file"
   ```

   This will run `bzip2` on the filename saved in a variable "$file". `bzip2` will compress the file to a new file named `$file.bz2`.
2. ```bsh
   stat -c %s "$file.bz2"
   ```

   This runs `stat` on the newly created compress `$file.bz2`:

   From `man stat`:

   ```
   stat - display file or file system status

       -c  --format=FORMAT
            use the specified FORMAT instead of the default
       %s    total size, in bytes
   ```

   So, this `stat` command will return the file size in bytes of the new file.
3. ```bsh
   $(some_command)
   ```

   This is called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

   > Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command.

   So, `var=$(some_command)` saves the **output** of some_command into a variable `var`.

---

In total:

```bsh
compress_size_bzip2=$(bzip2 "$file" ; stat -c %s "$file.bz2")
```

This runs `bzip2` and `stat` in a subshell. The output of the subshell is the size of the compressed file in bytes, which will be saved in a variable `$compress_size_bzip2`.

---

However, there is room for improvement:

You should combine the commands in the subshell with `&&`, so `stat` only runs when `bzip2` was successful.

If you don't need a compressed file, you should tell `bzip2` to compress to standard output with `-c` flag, and use `wc -c` to tell its size:

```bsh
compress_size_bzip2=$(bzip2 -c "$file" | wc -c)
```

Comment: The last command doesn't work; the file descriptor is a symbolic link and `stat` reads the size of the symlink itself.  (Always 64 bytes on my system).  You can see this by removing the `-c %s` option.  However, even if we get `stat` to follow the link with the `-L` option, the underlying file is a fifo so the size is only what is currently buffered; and since `stat` runs immediately `bzip2` doesn't have time to write anything and the reported size will be zero.  Instead you should use something like `bzip2 -c "$file" | wc -c`.

Comment: You are completely right. I replaced the wrong command. Thanks for the headsup.